# Responding to mouseMove events in stacked views

Tags: macos, cocoa

I have a window (NSWindow) with a series of views on it.  One of these views accepts mouseMove events.  I want to be able to connect a line between two different views with the mouse.  So, what I've done, is created a larger view that covers the entire window and I draw my line in this view.  This works fine.

The problem is that if I allow my larger, overlapping, view to accept mouseMove events so the line follows the cursor, then my visible view stops receiving mouseMove events.  This is a problem because I want certain objects to "light up" on the underlying view when my mouse hovers over them and I do this in that view's mouseMove method.

How can I get mouseMove methods called in both the invisible overlapping view and the visible view below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have the mouseMove method of the overlapping view send the mouseMove method to the underlying view.

Comment: Thanks, this works!  I just access my other view via [[[[self window] windowController] myOtherView] mouseMoved:theEvent] and now both views are responding to mouseMoved.

Answer (score 1):

check which options you are using to initialize your NSTrackingArea...
if I recall correctly you should be able to use NSTrackingActiveAlways and get the mouse events whether you are first responder or not.  it shouldn't matter if your views are stacked, as long as they register their own tracking areas they should receive the events...

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSTrackingArea_class/Reference/Reference.html